# Google maps circle - radius wrong size

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

on the map I'm creating for an applicaton (link below), Europe circle always appears greater than Latin America, even the value being lower. I tested various forms and is always represented that way.

How the circle radius work? Someone could show me what is wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/giotfr/owtw6t4z/5/

```
var citymap = {};

citymap['africa'] = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-8.783195, 34.508523),
    population: 3
};
citymap['asia'] = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.047863, 100.6196553),
    population: 38
};
citymap['europe'] = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.5259614, 15.2551187),
    population: 56
};
citymap['latin_america'] = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-4.4420385, -61.3268535),
    population: 61
};
citymap['northern_america'] = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.5517919, -112.8936787),
    population: 26
};
citymap['oceania'] = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-22.7359095, 140.0187653),
    population: 6
};

var cityCircle;

function initialize() {

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 2,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(16.12916136057057, 46.50333569999997),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
      mapOptions);

  for (var city in citymap) {
    var populationOptions = {
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      map: map,
      center: citymap[city].center,
      radius: Math.sqrt(citymap[city].population) * 100000
    };

    cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circle radius is in meters.  Due to the map projection, one meter at the equator is smaller that one meter at a higher latitude.

from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitude)

```
phi LONG
0°  111.320 km
15° 107.550 km
30° 96.486 km
45° 78.847 km
60° 55.800 km
75° 28.902 km
90° 0.000 km
```

So a circle of the same size will appear larger at higher latitudes.

To make  your circles in pixel sizes, use the map projection fromPointToLatLng and fromLatLngToPoint methods (and draw your own circle, the native google.maps.Circle uses the projection):

```
function drawCircle(center, radius, projection) {
    var i, angle, x1, y1;
    var circle = [];
    var point = projection.fromLatLngToPoint(center);
    var x = point.x;
    var y = point.y;
    for (var i = 0; i < 360; i += 10) {
        angle = i;
        x1 = radius * Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180);
        y1 = radius * Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180);
        circle.push(projection.fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(x + x1, y + y1)));
    }
    return circle;
}
```

code snippet:

```js
var citymap = {};

citymap['africa'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-8.783195, 34.508523),
  population: 4
};
citymap['asia'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.047863, 100.6196553),
  population: 32
};
citymap['europe'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.5259614, 15.2551187),
  population: 38
};
citymap['latin_america'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-4.4420385, -61.3268535),
  population: 65
};
citymap['northern_america'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.5517919, -112.8936787),
  population: 24
};
citymap['oceania'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-22.7359095, 140.0187653),
  population: 9
};

var cityCircle;

function initialize() {

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 1,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(25.12916136057057, -46.50333569999997),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
    mapOptions);

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    map.setCenter(mapOptions.center);
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'projection_changed', function() {
    var projection = map.getProjection();

    for (var city in citymap) {
      var populationOptions = {
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map: map,
        center: citymap[city].center,
        radius: Math.sqrt(citymap[city].population) * 100000,
        path: drawCircle(citymap[city].center, Math.sqrt(citymap[city].population) * 1, projection)
      };

      cityCircle = new google.maps.Polygon(populationOptions);
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function drawCircle(center, radius, projection) {
  var i, angle, x1, y1;
  var circle = [];
  var point = projection.fromLatLngToPoint(center);
  var x = point.x;
  var y = point.y;
  for (var i = 0; i < 360; i += 10) {
    angle = i;
    x1 = radius * Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180);
    y1 = radius * Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180);
    circle.push(projection.fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(x + x1, y + y1)));
  }
  return circle;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: .9em;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map">test</div>
```